# How do I solve this error using Python to insert text into a form control / dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to do my first web scraping project in `Python` using `Firefox`.  I'm using `Python version 3.7.4` and `Firefox Developer 71`.  Both are 64 bit and I'm using `Windows 10`.

The problem is trying to access this form control via `python`.  Ultimately I'd like to insert text into the form control and then web scrape the results.  However, I'm just trying to click on the object at the moment since it's playing hard to get.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.website.com/login/")

jcode_form = driver.find_element_by_id('ndcCode')
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(jcode_form)
time.sleep(6)  
hov.click()  
hov.perform()
```

The error I'm receiving says:

> WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

[Here is what I'm seeing on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfaV0.png)

The object I'm trying to work with is the form control at the top.

I've tried to troubleshoot this in a number of ways using action chains and the sleep function, but I keep receiving an error message.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which line of code is causing this error? can you post complete stack trace?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should add url for this page so we could see its HTML and test code.

Comment: your url is throwing error : `HTTP 404 - File not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few different things I would try here, including `send_keys()`, Javascript, or a combination of both. First, I would like to modify your locator to something more unique -- the ID `ndcCode` may or may not be used multiple times on the page, and if we locate multiple elements then this will throw unexpected results. You can verify this as follows:

```
elements_count = driver.find_elements_by_id("ndcCode")
print(str(len(elements_count))
```

If "1" does not print, then the locator strategy will need to be updated to something more specific. Regardless, I will use an updated strategy for the following code samples.

The first approach is just a simple `click()` followed by `send_keys()`:

```
jcode_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Start typing a Code, Drug, Product')]")
jcode_form.click()
jcode_form.send_keys("someText")
```

This is the most rudimentary approach, but best to rule this out first. Next, I would try Javascript approach, to perform the same actions:

```
jcode_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Start typing a Code, Drug, Product')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", jcode_form) # perform click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'someText';", jcode_form) # set the value
```

I am interested to hear your results after trying either of these code samples. If they do not work for you, feel free to comment on this answer and let me know of any errors you are encountering. If possible, I would be interested to see the URL you are testing against, so that I can attempt to debug and test these code samples.

Answer (score 0):

The following could should fix it:

```
    jcode_form = driver.find_element_by_id('ndcCode')
    jcode_form.click()
```

OR in one line:

```
    driver.find_element_by_id('ndcCode').click()
```